# Jenkins unable to find msbuild

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

getting started with Jenkins.  Learning as fast as I can!  Trying to setup msbuild in the tools config.  i have this:

[image]

Then I have a job set up to do a build using an explicit setting and another using the msbuild from above:

[image]

When I run this job, the first build works but the second one fails:

```
D:\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\VisionTest>"c:\program files (x86)\msbuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" TBSM.Vision.Database\TBSM.Vision.Database\TBSM.Vision.Database.sqlproj 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 2/27/2019 9:05:25 AM.
Project "D:\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\VisionTest\TBSM.Vision.Database\TBSM.Vision.Database\TBSM.Vision.Database.sqlproj" on node 1 (default targets).
GenerateSqlTargetFrameworkMoniker:
Skipping target "GenerateSqlTargetFrameworkMoniker" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
SqlBuild:
Skipping target "SqlBuild" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  TBSM.Vision.Database -> D:\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\VisionTest\TBSM.Vision.Database\TBSM.Vision.Database\bin\Debug\TBSM.Vision.Database.dll
SqlPrepareForRun:
  TBSM.Vision.Database -> D:\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\VisionTest\TBSM.Vision.Database\TBSM.Vision.Database\bin\Debug\TBSM.Vision.Database.dacpac
Done Building Project "D:\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\VisionTest\TBSM.Vision.Database\TBSM.Vision.Database\TBSM.Vision.Database.sqlproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.35

D:\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\VisionTest>exit 0 
FATAL: "c:\program files (x86)\msbuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe"  doesn't exist
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I figure its just me being a noob.  Why does Jenkins find msbuild.exe in the first build step but not the second?  What do I need to change?

Update:  I also tried it like this:

[image]

And selected MSBuildAgent in the job config, yet I still get:

```
FATAL: "c:\program files (x86)\msbuild\14.0\bin\"  doesn't exist
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please try after enabling the checkbox "Install automatically" and let us know if it works.

Comment: That wouldn't apply since the tool is already installed.  However, see the answer I received from the Jenkins community, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jenkins community found my error:

[Remove the double quotes surrounding the path](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56355?filter=-2)

thanks to [Lionel Cabasson](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=marshall777)!!

Answer (score 0):

In the Global Tool config you DO need to specify the full path to msbuild.exe and include the file name.  Ignore the error message it is a red herring.  Note: No double quotes around the path, not required.

[image: MSBuild Config]

Using this tool definition in a freestyle job requires an "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild" Step, not a Windows Batch step.

In a freestyle job:

1. Select the version of MSBuild you wish to use from the drop down
   list like you did.
2. Enter the WORKSPACE-relative path your project (or preferably
   solution) file.
3. In the Command Line arguments enter /t:Clean
4. Duplicate this step but with the same details but in the second one
   enter /t:Rebuild into the Command Line arguments

It is recommended that you migrate from Freestyle jobs to pipeline.